# anythingSlider fade images on top of each other

Tags: wordpress, anythingslider

am using the anythingSlider wordpress plugin

does any one know how to fade the images on top of each other as at the moment it fades them to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to "cross-fade" images from one to the next, AnythingSlider isn't currently set up to do that. Mostly because the images are floating left from each other.

I guess I could work on modifying the code to allow true cross-fading, but for now [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/aRyZ5/7/) shows what is currently possible - fade out to black and fade in from black.

You might also consider trying out [PlusSlider](https://github.com/JamyGolden/PlusSlider) which is similar to AnythingSlider but does have a true image cross-fade functionality.